# Different Wallpapers for Ubuntu Unity and Cinnamon

Tags: 16.04, unity, cinnamon, desktop-background

I recently installed Cinnamon through Ubuntu terminal and liked it so much.

The problem that I face, however, is that I want different wallpapers for Cinnamon and Ubuntu Unity. I also have KDE Plasma and it fulfils this requirement. I want the same with Cinnamon.

However, when I change desktop background in Cinnamon, the same wallpaper is applied to Ubuntu Unity. By now you must have understood that I don't want that.

Is there any way to do that?

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Cinnamon 3.6.7.

Comment: Well I am new to Cinnamon, and I think "Linux Mint 18" is its another name, pardon me if I am wrong. I originally had only Ubuntu and Plasma KDE, today I installed cinnamon. Now I want different wallpapers for Ubuntu and cinnamon.

Comment: No, Cinnamon is a desktop environment (DE), the DE environment in Ubuntu 16.04 is "Unity". "Linux Mint 18" is another distro (OS) which is based on Ubuntu and has Cinnamon as the main DE, but Linux Mint not an official Ubuntu derivative. So Linux Mint questions are off-topic here, but using Cinnamon with Ubuntu is fine here. I have made an edit accordingly to clarify your question. If you want to correct or modify, you can [edit] the question.

Comment: To answer your question I reckon it would be very hard to achieve. Usually it's not advisable to mix desktop environments, especially when they're closely related. It seems Unity and Cinnamon use the same schema to set the desktop background, so changing in one will also change for the other. You may consider creating multiple users and dedicate one user to one particular desktop environment.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will consider it. If you think there is nothing left worth mentioning, the topic can be closed.

Comment: I would suggest keeping the question open, others may come up with a proper solution.

Comment: Wait, you just want the wallpaper to change, depending on the environment you log in with? To the close voter: how on earth is this off-topic?

Comment: @pomsky I didn't considered that. As you wish, topic is still open ;D.